# jquery check onload which radiobutton is checked

Tags: jquery, radio-button, onload

given following html

```
<input id="IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_RadioButtonList1_0" 
       name="IBE1$IBE_NurFlug1$RadioButtonList1" value="Blue" type="radio">
<label for="IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_RadioButtonList1_0">Blue</label>

<input id="IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_RadioButtonList1_1" 
       name="IBE1$IBE_NurFlug1$RadioButtonList1" value="Green" checked="checked" 
       type="radio">
<label for="IBE1_IBE_NurFlug1_RadioButtonList1_1">Green</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pCBJL/2/

how can I perform actions like

If radiobutton blue is checked do ...
If radiobutton green is checked do...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [attribute-equals](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) (for the name match) and [`:checked`](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selectors, like this:

```
$(function() {
  var val = $("input[name='IBE1$IBE_NurFlug1$RadioButtonList1']:checked").val();
  if(val === "Blue") {
    //do something
  } else {
    //do something else
  }
});
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/pCBJL/3/).

Since you seem to be in ASP.Net though, you'll need a selector like this in your page:

```
$("input[name$='RadioButtonList1']:checked").val();
```

This is the [attribute-ends-with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/), to handle the naming container prefixes that ASP.Net appends.

Comment: thanks a lot. both answers are correct. the asp.net hints are top.

Answer (score 1):

grab the checked item and test against its value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
switch ($('input:checked').val()){
    case 'Green':
        //do something green
        break;
    case 'Blue':
        //do something blue
        break;
    default:
        //do something else
}
```

});